# Better Exposed Filters and a Node Relationship

Tags: views

I'm using [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) to enable datepickers for exposed date fields on my View. It's great, except that my view displays nodes via a taxonomy relationship. If I try to filter by node creation date, I don't get any Better Exposed Filters options. However, if I choose a date field that doesn't use a relationship (even if it doesn't exist on the term and therefore doesn't work), I get all the Better Exposed Filters options.

How can I best go about putting a popup datepicker on my exposed filter that uses a relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is related to the relationships. It looks like Drupal core date fields (post, changed, etc.) are not getting the proper BEF options, namely the datepicker. That's a bug in BEF -- it was mentioned at the end of [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1289370), but I never saw that because that issue is closed. Feel free to post a bug in the [BEF issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/better_exposed_filters) for this.

Thanks.